# Time complexity to generate all pairs in an array

Tags: c#, algorithm, time-complexity

Given an array of numbers, generate all unique pairs.

For example, given `[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]` the unique number pair would be:

```
(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5)

(2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5)

(3, 4), (3, 5)

(4, 5)
```

My solution is as follows:

```
int[] numbers = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
HashSet<Pair> pairs = new HashSet<Pair>();

for(int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
{
    for(int j = i + 1, j < numbers.Length; j++)
    {
        pairs.Add(new Pair(numbers[i], numbers[j]));
    }
}
```

I think the time complexity for this looks like O(n<sup>2</sup> - 1) *subtracting 1 because iteration of `j` is always 1 shorter than `i`*

Having done a bit of research into this kind of problem, I can't find any definitive answers as to whether this can be done faster. Are there any better solutions than O(n<sup>2</sup> - 1)?

Comment: I realised a while back that this specific case could be solved by adapting hte Bubble Sort Algorythm. BS compares every value exactly once against every other value. And you goal is combine every value exactly once with every other value. Same algorythm, same complexity.

Comment: As you're dealing with working code, this seems like a better fit for Code Review.

Comment: The only thing i can think of is with experience of many languages is a) is another language compiled up faster, b) if c# is viable, is a list the fastest, would you not to do better with maybe an array of fixed size etc.

Comment: please check this https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/124188/91608

Comment: @BugFinder those are trivial optimisations. I'm purely investigating time complexity here.

Comment: @DarshanDave that algorithm doesn't look like it's any better. They're using a `foreach` loop, and inside a condition on `.Contains`, which IIRC is O(n), so the whole thing would be something like O(n*n) _I think_

Comment: @series0ne okay

Comment: your program will not work if the element in your array is not unique, for example [1,1,2] -> the result should be (1,1), (1,2)

Comment: @PhamTrung it will now. I replaced `List` with `HashSet`.

Comment: Minor quibble: you don't write O(n^2-1).  You just write O(n^2).  Constant factors don't matter, scalar factors don't matter - only the fastest growing term matters.

Comment: How many unique pairs in `[ 1, 1, 1, 1, 2 ]` ?

Comment: @DavidConrad 2. (1,1) and (1,2)

Comment: Seems like it's only n^2 where n is the number of unique numbers present, then, not the total length of the array. Maybe apply the hash set to the numbers first, not just to the pairs at the end?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

One of the way to think about "is there faster way to solve the problem" is to look to the size of the output for some specific format (which you consider "probably the biggest/most difficult to solve").

If the output is `O(n^2)`, then you cannot solve the problem faster than in `O(n^2)`, because you have to spend at least `O(1)` for each output.

You can see the pattern there, if you have 5 numbers in format `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`, unique pairs take

```
4 pairs in first row
3 pairs in second row
2 pairs...
1 pair
```

because they look like

```
(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5)

(2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5)

(3, 4), (3, 5)

(4, 5)
```

If you have 20 variables in array (in format `[1, 2, 3,... 18, 19, 20]`), it will be as following:

```
19 pairs
18 pairs
...
2 pairs
1 pair
```

Therefore the output size is `(n-1) + (n-2) + (n-3) ... + 3 + 2 + 1`. You have to sum it (look to how to sum the series) and the result is `O(n^2)`

What was proved?

That the worst case scenario is AT LEAST `O(n^2)`.

Also note, that at this moment, we dont know real worst-case complexity - alghorithm can be even slower (we just find that some input takes `O(n^2)`). We know for sure that at least these data takes `O(n^2)`. It can be faster or slower for different input.

---

**Conlusion**: We have proof, that the algorithm takes at least `O(n^2)` time (as worst-case scenario), you created algorithm that is running in maximum of `O(n^2)` time (as described in spyc post) = You have optimal algorithm.

---

Extra info to OP's solution:
Detecting collisions with HashSet is only "pseudoConstant" and only for small numbers and "some luck". It takes `O(n)` for big amount of numbers. So you can end up in `n^2` output and each of them takes up to `n` to process which leads to `n^3` complexity.

You can solve it with preprocessing the task:

1) Sort it - it takes only `n log n`, so does not affect `n^2` anyway

2) Remove numbers that repeats more than twice `[1, 3, 3, 3, 5] -> [1, 3, 3, 5]`, it is `O(n)`

3)Then use your algorithm with this update:

3.1) In beginning of `for i` cycle: `if (number[i] == number[i-1]) continue;`

3.2) In beginning of `for j` cycle: Remember last pair. When adding new pair, look to the last pair and check if it is same or not. If so - `continue;`

Example:

```
Input: [1, 3, 3, 5]

1)i=0, j=1, number[0]=1, number[1]=3 -> add (1, 3)
2)i=0, j=2, number[0]=1, number[2]=3 -> same as last pair, use continue
3)i=0, j=3, number[0]=1, number[3]=5 -> add (1, 5)
4)i=1, j=2, number[1]=3, number[2]=3 -> add (3, 3)
5)i=1, j=3, number[1]=3, number[3]=5 -> add (3, 5)
6)i=2, before go to j-cycle, check number[i] === number[i-1] It is true, use continue
```

Comment: I feel like this answer should have more up-votes, because it definitively says "You have optimal solution"

Comment: @series0ne - I feel the same :D, however it took me more time to write it. You can accept my answer as "the most correct one".

Comment: Thanks for adding the bit about detecting collisions with `HashSet<T>`. That's also really useful!

Comment: *"What was prov[n]? That the algorithm needs AT LEAST `O(n²)` processing."* Not 100% correct. You have proven that the complexity enumerating the pairs is in `Ω(n²)` in the worst case. (Big-O denotes an upper bound only.)

Comment: @fabian - yes, thats good point. I was thinking how to put it in answer and not confuse people as usually if someone see `Ω` he/she automatically assumes "ah, I saw that many times, it is lower bound for algorithm, so any input takes at least `n^2`" - which is not true)

Comment: @libik: If you’re (rightfully!) concerned about people being confused due to commonly misused terminology, a good starting point is to use the terminology correctly yourself!

Comment: Thanks: I do get tired of people telling me HashSets are `O(1)`... that said, sorting can also take a longer than `n log n` depending on the algorithm (e.g. Quicksort worst case `n^2`, so still doesn't change the overall complexity as you said), but some do provide this as a guarantee (I think .NET mostly uses merge sorts, which do).

Comment: @wchargin - I do believe that my usage of complexity operators is still correct in that answer. We are looking for `O(...)` in worst case, so I am saying it will be at least this: `O(...)` (which is not wrong answer). Introducing `Ω` would require extra information, making the answer too long and not that relevant to the question itself

Comment: @VisualMelon - Sorting can be done in real `n log n` in worst-case by several algorithms (including merge sort), so we can definitely say "sorting takes `n log n`". If bubble sort or quick sort takes `n^2` in worst-case and my very-bad-sort takes `n^3` that really does not affect anything. PS: If you are wondering why someone is using quick sort if it is `n^2`, the answer is easy - in average case it takes `n log n` (hard to prove, you have to think about all possible permutation and count the average), it has O(1) memory and low hidden constant (i.e. it does not swap numbers that much)

Comment: @libik perhaps I wasn't clear: I was citing Merge Sort as a sort that is worst-case `n log n`. I appreciated your answer because it didn't assume that the hashset will perform well, and just wanted to clarify that point with regard to sorting also.

Answer (score 13):

It goes as follows:

```
first for loop - O(n)
    second for loop - O(n-1)
```

**Optimal** Time complexity  :

[image]

- Even though that one iteration is negligible, and you should calculate the time complexity for worst case scenario, which is [image]

You can also use binomial coefficient for permutations, to get number of permutations of a certain string. For example:

[image]

If you have 6 digits *{0,1,2,3,4,5}* (n=6), and you want to know how many different permutations you can make, i.e : (3,5) , (5,3) etc... then the (k=2, two digits in each group), the amount of permutations will be:

[image]  **different** permutations, do note though that in this case (3,5) , (5,3) are counted individually, so the order of it all matters. If you want (5,3) and (3,5) to be counted as one **combination** then the equation goes as follows:

[image]

---

### Example implementation, calculating permutations!

```
static long factorial(long x) // calcs the factorial TimeCmplx = O(n)
{
    if (x == 1)
        return x;
    return x * factorial(x - 1);
}

static long permutations(long n , long k) //Check that (n , k) >= 0
{            
    // Permutations , n!/(n-k)!
    return factorial(n) / factorial(n - k);
}
```

Comment: Your answer is much appreciated, however the last sentence went straight over my head.

Comment: Are you able to provide some sort of pseudo-code for that expression?

Comment: How is the complexity of the inner loop `O(n-1)`? It seems to be `O(n-i-1)` to me.

Comment: It's O(n) , not O(n-i-1) all you car about is the largest growing complexity . which is O(n)

Answer (score 6):

> I think the time complexity for this looks like O(n2 - 1) subtracting 1 because iteraton of j is always 1 shorter than i

If it mattered (big-O-notation usually you only write the term with the fastest growth), there you have iterations of i over [0,n) each containing an iteration of j over [i+1,n) so the number of iterations is (n∙(n-1))/2 not n²-1.

Also your edit changing to HashSet rather than list changes the worst case execution, though not the [amortised value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30504415/how-can-a-hashset-offer-constant-time-add-operation) - if Pair.GetHashCode() were always to return the same value, you'd have bumped it up to O(n³), as in cases where collisions are common hash set insertion becomes O(n) rather than constant.

Comment: Sorry, could you elaborate on that last paragraph. I'm not entirely sure what you mean?

Comment: Although the amortised cost of adding n items to a List is O(n), the cost of adding an item to a hashset depends on whether the hashset has to scan for a hash collision. So if your implementation of Pair has a poor implementation of GetHashCode, every time you add something to the hash set it needs to scan through every item already in the hash set, effectively adding another nested loop into the procedure.

Answer (score 1):

This is an **area of a triangle** algorithm.

You have **N** inputs, and you want **a triangle of outputs**.

Your output triangle has a **height** of **N-1** and a **width** of **N-1**.

```
Area of a triangle = height * width / 2
                   = (N-1)  * (N-1) / 2
                   = (N^2 - 2N + 1) / 2
```

**`O(n^2 - n)`** will always be the minimum/optimal algorithm cost!