# Is it possible to get distinct values from JSONObject in java

Tags: java, json, unique, distinct

I have a json file that contains 500k Objects and this is its format:

```
"WORKORDER": [
            { 
                "Attributes": { 
                    "SITEID": {
                        "content": "BEDFORD"
                    },
                    "WONUM": {
                        "content": "1000"
                    },
                    "WOPRIORITY": {
                        "content": 2
                    },
                    "WORKTYPE": {
                        "content": "CM"
                    }
                }
            },
            { 
                "Attributes": { 
                    "SITEID": {
                        "content": "BEDFORD"
                    },
                    "WONUM": {
                        "content": "1000-10"
                    },
                    "WORKTYPE": {
                        "content": "CM"
                    }
                }
            }
```

Im geting the distinct values like this :

```
for (int i = 0; i < WORKORDER.length(); i++) {  
                         JSONObject obj = WORKORDER.getJSONObject(i); 

                         JSONObject att = obj.getJSONObject("Attributes"); 

                         if( att.has(col)){ // getting col from params in the servlet

                             JSONObject column = att.getJSONObject(col);
                           Object  colval =   column.get("content");

                           if(!(list.contains(colval))) {
                              out.println( colval); 
                               list.add(colval);

                             }
```

But it takes long time for only 5000 objects !

Is there any way to get the distinct values of any column without parsing the whole Json file, otherwise parsing only the column needed.

Comment: You can use a `Set` instead of a `List`. (if `list` stand for a `List`). That would be a "simpler" code. Now to filter the JSON directly... unless you can change the JSON generation, you still need to read the JSON (`JSONObject` is just a parser).

Comment: you can try to convert it into a csv, and then fetch the needed column

Comment: @AxelH will it accelerate the parse when using the set ???

Comment: @PankajSinghal but it will take time also for converting into csv than fetching !!

Comment: Yes and no. It depends on the implementation you take. Using an `HashSet` would do it since it use buckets. For the moment, this is the `contains` method that kill you, it need to iterate the list for each element of the JSON. At first it's okay, but when you already have 1000 items, those will be iterated 400K times mores.

Answer (score 1):

You are iterating on a JSON with 500k elements. For each element you check if it was previously added in a `List`. That means your logic will iterate the list 500k times.

Instead, you should use a `HashSet`, first, the `Set` prevent duplicated value. So you just need to `set.add(value)` but the most interesting is the fact that the instance have a constant complexity value. Since it used buckets to organize the value, it doesn't have to iterate the `Set` fully.

You can read more about that [in *amit* answer's about *How can a HashSet offer constant time add operation?*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30504828/4391450)

> Note that HashSet gives amortized and average time performance of O(1), not worst case. This means, we can suffer an O(n) operation from time to time.
>   So, when the bins are too packed up, we just create a new, bigger array, and copy the elements to it.

Note that to use any `Hash####` implementation, you need to make sure the instance you store implements `hashCode` and `equals` correctly. You can find out more about this [in the community post about *What issues should be considered when overriding equals and hashCode in Java?*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27609/4391450).

Now for the solution :

```
Set<Object> sets = new HashSet<>();
for (int i = 0; i < WORKORDER.length(); i++) {  
    // ...
    Object  colval =   column.get("content");
    if(sets.add(colval)){ //`add` return true if it wasn't present already.
        out.println( colval); 
    }
}
```

I kept the `Object` type but this should be correctly typed, at least to be sure that those instance are implementing those methods as needed.

`colval` being an `Object`, it is possible it doesn't implements correctly the methods needed so I suggest you parse it correctly. You should use `column.getString("content)` instead or check the instance type.

---

To validate this, I have used a method to create a fake JSON:

```
public static JSONObject createDummyJson(int items) {
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    JSONArray orders = new JSONArray();
    json.put("order", orders);

    JSONObject attributes;
    JSONObject item;
    JSONObject order;

    Random rand = new Random();
    String[] columns = {"columnA", "columnB", "columnC", "columnD"};

    for(int i = 0; i < items; ++i) {
        order = new JSONObject();
        attributes = new JSONObject();
        order.put("Attributes", attributes);
        orders.put(order);

        for(int j = 0; j < rand.nextInt(1000) % columns.length; ++j) {
            item= new JSONObject();
            long rValue = rand.nextLong();
            item.put("content",  j%3 == 0 ? ("" + rValue ) : rValue );
            attributes.put(columns[j], item);
        }
    }
    return json;
}
```

Then ran a basic benchmark for both method and had the following results :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final int jsonLength = 500_000;
    JSONObject json = createDummyJson(jsonLength);
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    List<Object> list = parseJson(json);
    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.format("List - Run in %d ms for %d items and output %d lines%n", end-start, jsonLength, list.size());

    start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Set<Object> set = parseJsonSet(json);
    end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.format("Set - Run in %d ms for %d items and output %d lines%n", end-start, jsonLength, set.size());
}

public static List<Object> parseJson(JSONObject json) {
    String col = "columnC";

    JSONArray array = json.getJSONArray("order");

    List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject obj = array.getJSONObject(i);
        JSONObject att = obj.getJSONObject("Attributes");
        if (att.has(col)) { // getting col from params in the servlet
            JSONObject column = att.getJSONObject(col);
            Object colval = column.get("content");

            if (!(list.contains(colval))) {
                //System.out.println(colval);
                list.add(colval);
            }
        }
    }

    return list;
}

public static Set<Object> parseJsonSet(JSONObject json) {
    String col = "columnC";

    JSONArray array = json.getJSONArray("order");

    Set<Object> set = new HashSet<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject obj = array.getJSONObject(i);
        JSONObject att = obj.getJSONObject("Attributes");
        if (att.has(col)) { // getting col from params in the servlet
            JSONObject column = att.getJSONObject(col);
            Object colval = column.get("content");

            if (set.add(colval)) {
                //System.out.println(colval);
            }
        }
    }

    return set;
}
```

> List - Run in 5993 ms for 500000 items and output 46971 lines
>   Set - Run in 62 ms for 500000 items and output 46971 lines

I even went to a JSON with 5M row (removed the List that would never end)

> Set - Run in 6436 ms for 5000000 items and output 468895 lines

## Important, remove the line that print in console every new insertion, it will reduce the execution time a bit.

Comment: @AnasElbenney Please note the last part, use `column.get` isn't safe with this logic, use `getString("content")` instead. (Forgot you've shown the JSON...)

Comment: but I dont know if the user choose a string column or number !

Comment: sorry it is doing it too long too, the same time for both (set and list)

Comment: Ok @AnasElbenney I will generate a dummy JSON to do some testing. I will get back to you when this is done (this evening GMT probably).

Comment: @AnasElbenney I have ran with a "similar" json and have validated the difference. If it didn't worked, then this is not the `Set` that takes time...

Comment: but im calling from ajax this servlet to give me back the distinct values ! how i will doing it without printing?

Comment: @AnasElbenney You have a request in Ajax sendind you a JSON and you directly print in the response output a line by line result (not a JSON) ? Why don't you generate a JSON from the `Set` ? Just check if this is not the print that is slow, at least we can confirm that this solve the first problem.

Comment: but Im printing them as list in html like this :out.println( "<li>"
               +colval
               +"</li>");

Comment: when i do it with sets and just for 5k jsonobject it takes 17000ms !! its weird

Comment: i also tried without printing anything and its lasts the same duration

Comment: @AnasElbenney Can you try with the code I have used for the test ? It generate a "random" JSON. I would guess the problem is mostly to parse the `String` into the `JSONObject`. On what are you running this, a Raspberry ;) ?

Comment: im receiving `JSONObjects` from Link , and doing `HttpURlconnection` and `BufferedReader` to read the json file! it seams that this method is solwing down the fetch ?

Comment: That indeed a possibilities @AnasElbenney . Hard to tell. All I can say is that the example provided in the answer show a drastic improvement to read a JSON and store value in a `Collection`. For the rest. This required more information, you need to check what is taking so long ... all I can do is guess. A basic way would be to print `System.currentTimeInMillis()` on specific point to see how long it take. I can't tell you more than that.